# jsTree: How to *set* opened/selected node by path (not ID)?

Tags: jstree

So, I can *get* the full path of a selected node like so (thanks to @ggrandes for that one):

```
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
  var path = data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/');
  console.log('Selected: ' + path); 
})
```

What I now need, is to *set* select/open a node according to a given path.

All the solutions I've found so far refer to some mysterious ID, which appears to simply assume that the data in question has IDs. My problem is that I don't. It's simply a recursive JSON dict/array describing a directory layout. All I have with each node, is its name and a list of its children (and their names and children and so forth).

So, what I need is something like:

```
data.instance.set_path('/some/arbitrary/path');
```

Is it possible to do this with jsTree in some reasonable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a full path of every item on the server-side and using that as an ID that could then be selected on the client-side. As far as I can tell, there is no other way, at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selectNodeFromPath(pathString) {
  // Split the path string into an array of node names
  var pathArray = pathString.split('/');

  // Start at the root node
  var currentNodeId = '#';

  // Traverse the tree one node at a time
  for (var i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
    // Get the child nodes of the current node
    var childNodes = $('#tree').jstree('get_children_dom', currentNodeId);

    // Find the child node with the matching name
    var matchingChildNode = null;
    for (var j = 0; j < childNodes.length; j++) {
      var childNode = childNodes[j];
      var childNodeText = $('#tree').jstree('get_text', childNode);
      if (childNodeText === pathArray[i]) {
        matchingChildNode = childNode;
        break;
      }
    }

    // If a matching child node was found, update the current node ID
    // and continue to the next node in the path
    if (matchingChildNode) {
      currentNodeId = matchingChildNode;
    } else {
      // If no matching child node was found, the path is invalid
      console.log('Invalid path:', pathString);
      return;
    }
  }

  // If we made it to the end of the path, select the final node
  $('#tree').jstree('select_node', currentNodeId);
}
```